# knitr cuts off coord_fixed ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I'm experiencing some behavior where knitr cuts off part of a ggplot2 image when i used `coord_fixed(ratio = 1)`.

#### mwe.Rmd

````
---
title: "mwe"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

data <- list(
  x1 = 0:6,
  y1 = 0,
  x2 = rep(0:6, 2),
  y2 = rep(c(0, 1), each = 7) * -1,
  labels = paste("Label", 1:7)
)

g <- ggplot() + geom_text(aes(0:6, 0.75), label = data$labels)

g_unfixed_1 <- g + geom_raster(aes(data$x1, data$y1))
g_fixed_1 <- g_unfixed_1 + coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
g_unfixed_2 <- g + geom_raster(aes(data$x2, data$y2))
g_fixed_2 <- g_unfixed_2 + coord_fixed(ratio = 1)

g_unfixed_1
g_fixed_1
g_unfixed_2
g_fixed_2
```
````

Called with the the following, I can see the top margin for `g_fixed_1` is slightly cut off compared to the top margin for `g_fixed_2`:

```
rmarkdown::render("mwe.Rmd", clean = F)
```

I looked at the PDFs produced by knitr and the top of the plot is a little cut off with `g_fixed_1`:

[image: g_fixed_1]

compared to `g_fixed_2` (two rows of data):

[image: g_fixed_2]

Comment: ...... you are risking downvotes, when you do not provide [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please do. Very often, when one actually tries to bring it down to the core problem, the problem solves itself magically

Comment: Rmarkdown documents have default `fig.width` and `fig.height`, and individual chunks take these arguments as well. This usually defaults to 7" by 4". It looks like you've crammed 2 plots into a 7" by 4" space. The figure size doesn't adjust to fit the plot, since `ggplot` don't inherently have set dimensions, so you need to adjust the figure size to fit

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, but I included a minimal complete Rmd document that reproduces the effect if you render it and look at the produced PDF. The figures I included are two separate images that demonstrate the top margin being cut off when the plot data only contains one row and a bigger margin when the data contains two or more rows. This is also seen in the plot PDF figures when the clean = F option is used.

Comment: So did you try setting the `fig.width` and `fig.height` arguments to fit your plot?

Comment: Yes, I tried setting `fig.height = 5` but that still creates cut off images when plotting the `coord_fixed(ratio = 1)` plots.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and solved it using:

```
p + scale_y_continous(limits = c(0, max(value)*1.1))
```

In my example I was doing a loop over a file of plots, so was something like this:

```
    for(n in names(tabla)) {
    plots_ms[[n]] +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(plots_ms[[n]]$data$ms)*1.1))
}
```